# jquery .serialize doesn't work on dynamically generated form

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I'm working with Java/Spring inside a .jsp.

I'm dynamically loading a form (form tags inlcuded) from myForm.jsp inside a div within myPage.jsp and trying to make an ajax post call with said data. When I call jQuery .serialize and print out the data, it comes back empty.

However, If include the form tags inside myPage.jsp and just load the inputs, everything works fine.

Is there something about dynamically loading a whole form that I'm doing wrong?

myPage.jsp

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if(window.attachEvent)
    {
        window.attachEvent('onload', LoadTable);
    } else
    {
        if(window.onload)
        {
            var curronload = window.onload;
            var newonload = function()
            {
                curronload();
                LoadTable();
            };
            window.onload = newonload;
        } else
        {
            window.onload = LoadTable;
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click','#myFormSubmit',function()
    {
        var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
        console.log("data " + data);
        //data is empty!

        return false;
    });

    function LoadTable()
    {
        $.get('/url', function(data) {
            $('#myForm').append(data);
            console.log('Data was fetched.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<body>
<div id='myDiv'>
    <!-- myForm.jsp gets loaded here -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

myForm.jsp

```html
<form id='myForm' name='config_cache' action='config_cache' method='POST'>
  <input id='input1' type="checkbox" name="input1" value="true">
  <input id='myFormSubmit' name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: try dump data only without any string and if you dump form #myForm is jquery object?

Comment: Maybe phpjs serialize works better? http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/

Comment: or try var data = $(this).closest('#myForm').serialize(); instead of var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

Comment: It boils down to the button `#myFormSubmit`. If it is replaced when the form is loaded, then `$(document).on('click','#myFormSubmit',function() {...}` is irrelevant - *that* button no longer exists. You probably have *another* button with the same id, but with no click handler attached.

Comment: dareMachine: None of those worked :( and data is still blank even with no string. 

Roamer - there are no other buttons with that ID, I checked names and IDs for all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting - you just haven't submitted any data to it.  Your form's only input is a checkbox which isn't checked.  Per the documentation for [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. **Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked.** Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Substitute your form with this one and submit it.  You should see:

data someName=This+is+a+test&input1=true

```
<form id='myForm' name='config_cache' action='config_cache' method='POST'>                                                                                    
    <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="This is a test">                                                                                              
    <input id='input1' type="checkbox" name="input1" value="true" checked>                                                                                    
    <input id='myFormSubmit' name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">                                                                                      
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need your checkbox serialized in a form where it would be submitted with a null value if it wasn't selected. This is a common requirement for javascript form serialization. Take a look at this jquery plugin that handles that requirement:

https://github.com/davemaple/jquery-form2json

This would allow your form to serialize as:

`{ "input1": null }`

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic data use .appendTo() [https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/]  instead of .append()!

I know how it sounds, but it works!